# Portable texlive 2019 not working: fmtutil error

Tags: texlive, fmtutil

I got portable texlive 2019 installed in Win10 and added the bin\win32 to system $PATH variable. Cmd command `tex --version` gives

```
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX)
kpathsea version 6.3.1
Copyright 2019 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.
```

but `latex sample2e.tex` gets me into

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=latex)
restricted \write18 enabled.

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt latex.fmt

The command name is D:\Program Files\texlive\2019\bin\win32\mktexfmt
Running the command D:\Program Files\texlive\2019\bin\win32\fmtutil-user.exe
fmtutil [ERROR]: -user mode but path setup is -sys type, bailing out.
D:\Program Files\texlive\2019\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:907: command failed with exit code 1:
perl.exe "d:\Program Files\texlive\2019\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\fmtutil.pl"  --user --byfmt latex
I can't find the format file `latex.fmt'!
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Method to solve:

1. Open `Administrator:Windows Powershell` from `cmd`.
2. Input the command:

   ```
   PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>D:\texlive2019\2019\bin\win32\fmtutil-sys.exe --all
   ```
3. Copy from Windows 10 `C:\VTRoot\HarddiskVolume2\texlive2019\2019\texmf-var\web2c` to `D:\texlive2019\2019\texmf-var\web2c`.
4. Run the `.tex` source file, it should be okay.